# What build is best for jax

Tags: league-of-legends

Well I don't really play a lot of jax but what build is best for him and in what situations?
Plus any tips for vs a jax is appreciated.
If there are any places where I could learn jax a bit better

Comment: Are you have difficult in playing Jax versus some champion or an specific lane? What have you already tried?

Comment: An AD bruiser jax is the most ideal, but it all depends on your opponents, and how well you are doing. If you are looking for a build that works nearly all the time, I would recommend Triforce+Botrk, into some fighter/bruiser items. (Omen, Visage, etc)

Comment: Um yeah as jax vs renekton/malphite and Olaf those champs I really can't jax against any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great overall endgame build for Jax is Ninja Tabi, Blade of the Ruined King, Trinity Force, Randuin's Omen, and Guardian's Angel. The last slot can be used to build another defensive or offensive item depending on how you're doing.

The best build for Jax is not full AD or full AP or full tank, he has A LOT of attack speed so on-hit is good for him (BotRK and Trinity both have on-hit effects) while his ult and E help provide a lot of defence, meaning you can invest in offensive early.

In the current meta, Jax is played in the top lane, which is usually where tanks go. That is why you build Randuin's and GA later on so he can get tanky.

Hope this helped :)